# Shallow routing in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Having a rough time with my routes in my rails 3 app, I want to have shallow routes like this:

```
/san-francisco/union-square
```

But my router insists on having them like so:

```
/cities/san-francisco/neighborhoods/union-square
```

I've used this for my `routes.rb`

```
shallow do
  resources :cities do
    resources :neighborhoods do
      resources :locations
    end
  end
end
```

But still I have this:

```
city_neighborhood_locations GET  /cities/:city_id/neighborhoods/:neighborhood_id/locations(.:format)
```

Shouldn't it look like:

```
city_neighborhood_locations GET  /:city_id/:neighborhood_id/:id(.:format)
```

I'm not sure how to fix this, additionally I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with my links, I want to be able to use the syntax:

```
link_to neighborhood.name, [:city, neighborhood]
```

but that seems to invert the `:id`, and `:neighborhood_id` when the request comes to the controller, any help on this would be really really helpful!

Comment: Nested resources still use the name of the resources, not sure what made you believe otherwise. Not sure about the link_to thing, doesn't happen for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you're looking for is not typically known as "shallow routing".

Shallow routing, as Rails defines it, would look like this:

```
city_neighborhoods         GET  /cities/:city_id/neighborhoods
new_city_neighborhood      GET  /cities/:city_id/neighborhoods/new
(create_city_neighborhood) POST /cities/:city_id/neighborhoods
neighborhood               GET  /neighborhoods/:neighborhood_id
```

Without shallow routing, that last route would be:

```
city_neighborhood          GET  /cities/:city_id/neighborhoods/:neighborhood_id
```

Shallow routing lets you nest a resource underneath another resource (neighborhood under city in this case), but gives you absolute/un-nested routes for the nested resource when the nesting isn't necessary.

This makes sense when you're referencing the nested resource with unique identifiers that are *not* dependent on the ID of the parent resource. In your example, that's *not* true (there's potentially a "Union Square" outside of San Francisco; there's definitely going to be duplicates like "Chinatown"), so you probably do *not* want shallow routes for this case.

What you're wanting is positionally-dependent routing, where the type of resource is assumed/fixed depending on where it appears in the URL. (For instance, you couldn't have anything other than a "neighborhood" follow a "city" under the scheme you outlined.)

I don't think the Rails `resource(s)` commands will support that by default, but you could probably do it with manual `match` commands. This is off the top of my head:

```
match ":city_id", :controller => "cities", :action => "show"
match ":city_id/:neighborhood_id", :controller => "neighborhoods", :action => "show"
```

This is still RESTful/resource-based, it's just not using the standard Rails way of naming routes.

Comment: +1 — `resources` handles this fine, you just specify `:path => '/:city_name'` or similar. Nesting still works and everything, so you could have `resources :users, :path => '/:username' { resources :posts, :path => ':/post_slug' }`, giving you routes like `/coreyward/foo-bar` that route to `PostsController` with a `username` param and a `post_slug` param.