# Rails 4 [Best practices] Nested resources and shallow: true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-routes

The following post is based on Rails 4.

I am currently looking for a best-practice about the multiple nested resources (more than 1), and the option shallow: true.

Initially in my routes, there was this :

```
resources :projects do 
  resources :collections
end
```

The associated routes are :

```
    project_collections GET    /projects/:project_id/collections(.:format)          collections#index
                        POST   /projects/:project_id/collections(.:format)          collections#create
 new_project_collection GET    /projects/:project_id/collections/new(.:format)      collections#new
edit_project_collection GET    /projects/:project_id/collections/:id/edit(.:format) collections#edit
     project_collection GET    /projects/:project_id/collections/:id(.:format)      collections#show
                        PATCH  /projects/:project_id/collections/:id(.:format)      collections#update
                        PUT    /projects/:project_id/collections/:id(.:format)      collections#update
                        DELETE /projects/:project_id/collections/:id(.:format)      collections#destroy
               projects GET    /projects(.:format)                                  projects#index
                        POST   /projects(.:format)                                  projects#create
            new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)                              projects#new
           edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format)                         projects#edit
                project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)                              projects#show
                        PATCH  /projects/:id(.:format)                              projects#update
                        PUT    /projects/:id(.:format)                              projects#update
                        DELETE /projects/:id(.:format)                              projects#destroy
```

I read in the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#limits-to-nesting) about the limitation of nested resources :

> Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep.

Ok. Then, like the documentation said, I'm gonna use "shallow" in my routes instead.

```
shallow do
  resources :projects do 
    resources :collections
  end
end
```

The associated routes are :

```
   project_collections GET    /projects/:project_id/collections(.:format)     collections#index
                       POST   /projects/:project_id/collections(.:format)     collections#create
new_project_collection GET    /projects/:project_id/collections/new(.:format) collections#new
       edit_collection GET    /collections/:id/edit(.:format)                 collections#edit
            collection GET    /collections/:id(.:format)                      collections#show
                       PATCH  /collections/:id(.:format)                      collections#update
                       PUT    /collections/:id(.:format)                      collections#update
                       DELETE /collections/:id(.:format)                      collections#destroy
              projects GET    /projects(.:format)                             projects#index
                       POST   /projects(.:format)                             projects#create
           new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)                         projects#new
          edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format)                    projects#edit
               project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)                         projects#show
                       PATCH  /projects/:id(.:format)                         projects#update
                       PUT    /projects/:id(.:format)                         projects#update
                       DELETE /projects/:id(.:format)                         projects#destroy
```

The major difference I see is the "show" of collections, this specific one :

```
collection GET    /collections/:id(.:format)                      collections#show
```

So if I I'm correct, the link for the show action for a collection is :

```
<%= link_to 'Show", collection_path(collection)%>
```

and should return something like this : "http://example.com/collections/1"

BUT ! 2 things :

- This is not working. I'm getting instead "http://example.com/projects/1".
- Even if it was working, it's actually IMO pretty bad because I loose the REST basic that say "Collection is child of project, then the url should be "localhost/project/1/collections/1"

I don't understand what is the interest of shallow if I loose the big advantage of Rest actions. And what is the interest to loose the "Show" action as well ? I already posted this to SO, but the only comment i got is "It's something normal". I don't believe this is a normal behavior to "remove" an action from the rest API ?

Yes, it might be convenient for the helpers to use shallow, but it is NOT AT ALL convenient for the rest, you loose all the interest of "one collection is nested to one project, so this is reflected in the URL".

I don't know if there is another way to do this, it's true that shallow allow more flexibility about the helpers, but it's false that it is REST compliant. So, is there any chance to get the "helpers" working (it's pretty awesome to have "nested3_path(collection)" instead of "nested1_nested2_nested3([nested1.nested2.nested3, nested1.nested2, nested1])", and keeping the "url part "nested1/123/nested2/456/nested3/789" ?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the server for the routes to take effect?

According to the doc
`resources :posts, shallow: true do
  resources :comments
end`

will produce
`resources :posts do
  resources :comments, except: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
end
resources :comments, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]`

which sound like you are doing

Comment: The server does indeed have to be restarted for routes to take effect.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't believe that Rails offers any built-in way to have the URLs use the full hierarchy (e.g. `/projects/1/collections/2`) but also have the shortcut helpers (e.g. `collection_path` instead of `project_collection_path`).

If you really wanted to do this, you could roll out your own custom helper like the following:

```
def collection_path(collection)
  # every collection record should have a reference to its parent project
  project_collection_path(collection.project, collection)
end
```

But that would be quite cumbersome to manually do for each resource.

---

I think the idea behind the use of `shallow` routes is best summed up by the documentation:

> One way to avoid deep nesting (as recommended above) is to generate
>   the collection actions scoped under the parent, so as to get a sense
>   of the hierarchy, but to not nest the member actions. In other words,
>   to only build routes with the minimal amount of information to
>   uniquely identify the resource

source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting

So while this may not be REST-compliant (as you say), you aren't losing any information because each resource can be uniquely identified and you are able to walk back up the hierarchy assuming your associations are set up properly.

Comment: While it's not built into Rails, [Inherited Resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) (IR) has nesting and helpers that might help. It might be good instead to be explicit and not use IR if it is just a handful of cases in which this is done, and it also can restrict or complicate controller implementation/debugging, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 10):

Since there's an `id` for a `Collection`, it's redundant to nest the route under the Project except for the `index` and `create` actions.

There's a rule about URL's where there's only supposed to be one URL to GET (with 200) a given resource, if there are other URL's you should redirect to it. So you might have a route `/projects/:id/collections/:collection_id` that redirects to `/collections/:collection_id`.

In your case, a Collection is tied to a Project, but that's not necessarily true for all relationships. Once you have the `:collection_id` you don't need to reference the context of the `Project` to access it.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I've been googling around looking for a basic explanation of the purpose of shallow routes! Assumption in the documentation is: you already know this. Judging from some of other answers here, a lot of others don't know either! What you are saying is if you are for example editing a comment by :id, it doesn't make sense to nest that under a project, because the comment :id is independent of the project id. Shallow just cleans up the routes to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

**Levels**

The notion you have to only use 1 level in your nested resources is only really applicable to the design of the system:

> The corresponding route helper would be publisher_magazine_photo_url,
>   requiring you to specify objects at all three levels. Indeed, this
>   situation is confusing enough that a popular article by Jamis Buck
>   proposes a rule of thumb for good Rails design:

I believe Rails can still handle multiple levels, although it's not recommended from a usability perspective

---

**Shallow**

Although I've seen shallow used before, I've never used it myself

From looking at the [documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), it seems shallow has a rather obscure purpose (I don't actually know why it's there). The problem is you aren't publicly passing the `post_id` parameter to your controller, leaving you to load the `collection` without an important param

I would surmise (and this is just speculation), that the aim is to pass the param you require behind the scenes, so you're left with a public "shallow" route:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :projects do 
   resources :collections, shallow: true
end
```

I would imagine you'd get a URL helper like this:

```
collection_path(project.id, collection.id)
```

This would come out as `domain.com/collection/2`

Comment: Yes you're right on the routes, but that don't help much for my question =/

Answer (score 2):

Though it can complicate things if you only need this for some models, it might be good to check out [Inherited Resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) (IR). It supports resource nesting, polymorphic belongs to's, and can automatically generate the shorter path and url helper methods you are looking for. The reason you don't hear about IR much anymore is that its original author and some other developers have somewhat abandoned it because of the complications that arise when trying to extend your controllers. However, it still has a community, and we've tried to extend it a bit more and focus more on ease of controller extensions with [Irie](https://github.com/FineLinePrototyping/irie).

The "best practice" in Rails depends on who you talk to.

Rails has traditionally been aimed at mostly basic CRUD for (non-nested) resources. Yes, it allows retrieving and updating nested resources, but it is assumed that doesn't happen quite as often.

However, what has been emerging in the Rails community is the [ActiveModel::Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers)/[json-api](https://github.com/json-api/json-api) approach. In this, usually not more than one level of nesting of resources occurs, and the nested resource is either a list of links or sideloaded small version of the child resources which you can then query on that resource to get more data. This has also been embraced by [Ember](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/)/[Ember Data](https://github.com/emberjs/data).

There are also [roar](https://github.com/apotonick/roar) and a number of other projects that aim to implement something closer to their understanding of something close to Roy Fielding's original vision of REST.

I think it just depends on what your design is and what you need. If efficiency is a goal, then the additional time to develop to be explicit and nest more may pay off. We currently use [AngularJS](https://github.com/angular) and [Irie](https://github.com/FineLinePrototyping/irie), for example. But, to each his own.

As as last note, be sure to avoid n+1 lookups through use of `includes(...)` (or similar) in your queries, otherwise all that nesting might bite you in performance.

Answer (score 1):

[From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7601020/793330) it seems shallow routes somewhat defy the convention of Rails, IMO.

I would think you wouldn't need the explicit path helper for a show route. The link_to helper should be able to infer it from the object's to_param method.

```
#your helper becomes 
link_to "show", collection
```

If you use the helper your way as you have above you probably need to pass the nested ID of the parent resource to the helper too.

```
link_to "show", collection_path([project, collection])
```